# 'none' prints for no apparent reason

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
print("Entre nummber 1: ")
num1 = float(input('> '))
print("Entre opperation: ")
op = input('> ')
print("Entre nummber 2: ")
num2 = float(input('> '))
result = print("Your Result is:")

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
    print(result)
    print("Done")

elif op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
    print(result)
    print("Done")

elif op == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)
    print(result)
    print("Done")

elif op == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
    print(result)
    print("Done")
elif op == '**':
    print(num1 ** num2)
    print(result)
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Entre a valid opperation")
```

I tried to make a calculator. It works fine but when at the end a 'none' pops up for no apparent reason .

I don't know why. Any help is appreciated.

This is the problem:
[image]

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Trrt.png)

Comment: `result = print(...)` assigns the return value of `print` to result. As `print` doesn't have anything relevant to return, the default value `None` is used. Just `print(...)` without the `result = ` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
result = print("Your Result is:")
```

`print("Your Result is:")` prints this string `"Your Result is:"` and returns `None` and now `result` is equal `None`. then `print(result)` prints `None`

Answer (score 2):

```
result = print("Your Result is:")
```

`print` return nothing `None`

value of result is `None`

```
print(result) #this is none
```

You should store it in a variable like

```
result = num1 + num2
print(result) #with calculated value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove result = print("Your result is :")
# Add this result = num1 'operation +/-/*/** etc' num2 after your if condittions.
# for example :
if op == "+":
    result = num1 + num2
    print("Your result is :",result)
if op == "-" :
    result = num1 - num2
    print("Your result is :",result)
# It will work fine.
```